# How can i print the changed value in array?

Tags: java

I'm setting up a 10x10 girds. I need to change some gird. But when i change the value it has not changed.Is there a problem with my for-loop? Or i need input the value in main,not in the for-loop?

```
import java.util.*;
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String [][]array = new String [10][10];

    printArray(array);
    array[0][0]="s";
    printArray(array);
}
public static void printArray(String [][]array){
    System.out.print("   ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.printf("%2d", i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("--+--------------------");

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        System.out.print(i + " |");
    for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
        array[i][j]=".";
        System.out.printf("%2s",array[i][j]);
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

This is the result,i have no idea how to make it change.

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
--+--------------------
0 | . . . . . . . . . .
1 | . . . . . . . . . .
2 | . . . . . . . . . .
3 | . . . . . . . . . .
4 | . . . . . . . . . .
5 | . . . . . . . . . .
6 | . . . . . . . . . .
7 | . . . . . . . . . .
8 | . . . . . . . . . .
9 | . . . . . . . . . .

    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
--+--------------------
0 | . . . . . . . . . .
1 | . . . . . . . . . .
2 | . . . . . . . . . .
3 | . . . . . . . . . .
4 | . . . . . . . . . .
5 | . . . . . . . . . .
6 | . . . . . . . . . .
7 | . . . . . . . . . .
8 | . . . . . . . . . .
9 | . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: This line: `array[i][j]=".";` doesn't look right. You override all the values to ".".

Comment: Your printArray() method should do just that, and only that. It should not initialize or change the contents of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to print a dot "." if the value is null, otherwise you want to print the value. Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][]array = new String [10][10];

    printArray(array);
    array[0][0]="s";
    printArray(array);
  }

  public static void printArray(String [][]array) {
    System.out.print("   ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%2d", i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("--+--------------------");

    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
      System.out.print(i + " |");
      for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++) {
        if (array[i][j] == null) {
          System.out.printf("%2s", ".");
        } else {
          System.out.printf("%2s", array[i][j]);
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```